# Can I perform filters on custom made columns?

Tags: sql, t-sql

Before I add the where clause, timeAssigned populates as an additional column, but I can not filter on it. Is it possible?

```
select id, DATEDIFF(minute, transactionHeader.clerkDateTime, getDate()) as timeAssigned 
from transactionHeader 
where timeAssigned > 5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is correct.  The alias defined in the `select` is not understood by the `where`.  I recommend moving the variable creation logic to the `from` clause, using a lateral join:

```
select th.id, v.timeAssigned
from transactionHeader th cross apply
     (values (DATEDIFF(minute, th.clerkDateTime, getDate()))
     ) v(timeAssigned)
where v.timeAssigned > 5
```

Comment: Very cool to know! Thank you. This got me exactly what I was trying to achieve with my posted query. I'll have to read up on cross apply, it seems very useful.

Comment: @PatrickSasquatch, please take a moment to mark this as your accepted answer by clicking the gray check mark to the left of the answer. It lets other users know the question has an answer, and rewards the user who answered with some reputation points, and you get some, too.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest option (without touching your query) is to produce a "table expression" that will include the new named column (built on the fly), so you can use it in the main query.

For example:

```
select * 
from ( -- your query as table expression "x" here
  select
    id, 
    DATEDIFF(minute, transactionHeader.clerkDateTime, getDate()) as timeAssigned 
  from transactionHeader 
  where timeAssigned > 5
) x
where timeAssigned > 5 -- your extra filtering condition here
```